# Deck app returns error when trying to use "secure open in browser" feature

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

When building a project, using laravel, mysql or any of the available project and then trying to launch the project using the "Open in secure browser" link will always result in an error.

[browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u33H.jpg)

I have tried it using Safari, Chrome, Firefox & Brave browsers and the same results with all of them, so I know its not browser specific.

There might be some configuration with my system or other dev environment that is clashing, I am using MacOS Monterey if it helps.

Attached is a screenshot of the browser open result.

I would like assistance in fixing this feature as the ability to test app development using SSL is quite useful & important with my current project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a port conflict on the MacOS environment. I made contact on the Deck app Github where they fixed it in a new release of their app, so it shouldn't happen to anyone else. If you find that SSL isn't working on your deck app, head over to the [Deck App Github](https://github.com/deck-app) and launch and issue, the contributors are extremely fast at responding and very helpful.